# Trouble scrolling a LoadNib UIView that's in a UIScrollView

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm using the Xamarin tools and am trying to load a view using LoadNib then add it to a UIScrollView. I'm doing something wrong. The view displays but I cannot get it to scroll. Code is below. What am I doing wrong?

```cs
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    scrollView = new UIScrollView (
        new RectangleF (0, 0, View.Frame.Width
                    , View.Frame.Height - NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Height));
    View.AddSubview (scrollView);

    var arr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("AboutView", this, null);
    var v = Runtime.GetNSObject(arr.ValueAt(0)) as UIView;
    scrollView.ContentSize = v.Frame.Size;
    scrollView.AddSubview(v);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this. scrollView.ContentOffset = new PointF(320,480);
SizeF size = new SizeF(320,315);

this.scrollMonth.ContentSize = size; 
this.viewNewRecord.Hidden = false;
```

if you are loading scroll from xib you can check the property bounce change the content size of scroll view then i think it showu